# Cocoa Document Won't Open Again After It's Closed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

This is a pretty weird issue. I have a table in my Cocoa application that displays a list of recently opened files. You can double click on an entry to open the associated file. Trouble is, though, after the file is opened once, whether through the Open panel, the Recent Documents menu, or through the aforementioned table, it can't be opened again until the application has quit and re-opened. *Other documents*, however, can be opened, but once they're closed they can't be opened again either.

This is pretty odd behavior, and I'm not sure what's causing it. But it's certainly annoying. For reference, the `Release on Closed` attribute of the window from Xcode does nothing and, if selected, does not do anything. I can't think of any other attributes which might cause this behavior. For reference, here's a photo of the attributes panel:

[image: A photo of the document window attributes panel.]

Here's the code for the table which opens the recently opened file:

```
- (void)respondToRecentFileDoubleClick {
    NSInteger clickedRow = [_recentFileBrowser clickedRow];

    if (clickedRow != -1) { // We're in the row.
        NSDocumentController *docControl = [NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController];
        NSURL *selectedDocument = (NSURL *)[docControl recentDocumentURLs][clickedRow];
        NSLog(@"Selected row %ld.", (long)clickedRow);
        [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:selectedDocument display:YES completionHandler:nil];
    }
}
```

The documentation for `openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:` says that the document won't be opened if it's already opened, but in this case, all of the document windows are closed, so that can't be what causes this behavior. And the `NSLog()` statement inside the `if` block prints, so I know the code is being executed.

Anyone know what might be causing this bizarre issue?

Answer (score 0):

From the Xcode image, it appears that you are using your own WindowController.  The default close menu item is wired up to call performClose.  The performClose method is implemented in NSWindow.  So, what is happening is that the window is closing, but the document is not removed from the open document list.  Try adding < NSWindowDelegate> to your WindowController interface (in the .h file).  Then add to your WindowController .m file:

```
- (void) windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
[ourdoc close];
}
```

Substitute whatever variable you using to hold your document reference for ourdoc.  Typically the method setDocument will get called with your document reference.  (Also in your WindowController.)

```
 - (void) setDocument:(NSDocument *)document {
ourdoc = (yourNSDocumentsubclass *)document;
}
```

completionHandler:nil change for debugging:

```
completionHandler:^(NSDocument *doc, BOOL documentWasAlreadyOpened, NSError *error) {
    if (documentWasAlreadyOpened) {
        NSLog(@"document was already opened");
        NSArray *rats  = [[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] documents];
        NSLog(@"%s  seriously: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, rats);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the evidence that I'm using my own `WindowController`? My Document class is a subclass of `NSDocument`, and the `File's Owner` is this Document class, not a window controller. I can try your suggestion though.

Comment: @SevenBits - I made a wrong assumption about the WindowController subclass.  Nevertheless, I believe that the document is not getting closed.  For debugging, you could probably put something along the lines of the following in your opendocument completion handler: (see edit in answer).